# Are button click events handled by the code behind or the view model? MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8

Imagine I have a username and password text box and one button to submit login details.

I have a class:

```
public class LoginCredentials
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I have a view model:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LoginCredentials LoginCredentials { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel( LoginCredentials loginCredentials )
    {
        // Implement loading from saved credentials if done so
        this.LoginCredentials = new LoginCredentials();
    }

    #region Properties
    public string Username {
        get { return LoginCredentials.Username; }
        set { LoginCredentials.Username = value; }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return LoginCredentials.Password; }
        set { LoginCredentials.Password = value; }
    }
    #endregion

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I have some xaml with data bindings to this view model:

```
...DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel}"...     
   <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,27,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" Margin="0,126,0,0" Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456"/>

        <Button Content="Log in" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="167,203,169,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    </Grid>
```

And finally, my code behind for the xaml:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Where do I put the click event that updates my LoginCredentials declared in my viewmodel which I then submit to my DomainModel ( which in this case is a service layer ).

If I add a click event that binds to a function in my viewmodel, I cannot know what the textbox fields for username and password will be because the viewmodel does not have access to the Username.text kind of methods.

Do I put some notifypropertychanged in the code behind for the button? yellllp. P.S this is my first windows phone app.

Answer (score 2):

> Where do I put the click event that updates my LoginCredentials declared in my viewmodel which I then submit to my DomainModel ( which in this case is a service layer ).

Typically, you wouldn't do this.  Instead, you'd add an `ICommand` within your `ViewModel`, and bind the Button's `Command` to the `ICommand`.  This allows you to decouple the logic and place it entirely within your ViewModel, and still use binding to call it.

The `ICommand` is typically implemented via some form of DelegateCommand, such as [this implementation for Windows Phone](http://davidsandor.com/post/2013/05/04/DelegateCommand-class-for-Windows-Phone-7-and-8.aspx).

> I cannot know what the textbox fields for username and password will be because the viewmodel does not have access to the Username.text kind of methods.

These are bound to properties within the ViewModel, so changes will automatically be reflected there.

Comment: Exacly, but if there's something only the `View` can do, you could use a little code behind. It is not a sin :)

Comment: so not only am I implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged, but i'm putting a comma at the end of that and also implementing the ICommand interface? right? Could you show me one example so I've got something to work on?

Comment: @JamesT I added an article link.  I've got a series that walks through this all (though it's WPF based) at http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/

Comment: @Tico Yes, that's true - but in this case, a "Log In" button wouldn't be a pure view concern ;)

Comment: Let me see if I can implement this... I'll come running if I get stuck :). thanks buddies!

Comment: @Reed Copsey Couldn't agree more! The `View` is dumb!

Comment: Okay so basically the DelegateCommand in your article is the function that runs... How do I link the button to this whole process? Binding?

Comment: Argh, I don't understand. Could you give me an example login button command added to my example. I'm finding it so hard to grasp! So when the button is pressed, it runs a command that allows me to submit the username and password to my service model. So 1) how do I bind the button to the viewmodel command, 2) how do I write the command that runs in the viewmodel, smpler the better

Comment: @JamesT I detail this here: http://reedcopsey.com/2009/12/28/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-5-commands/